# Guardar o número de linhas de um dataframe em uma variável

Tags: python

Eu tenho um dataframe que é gerado de forma randômica variando seu número de linhas. Eu gostaria de guardar esse número variável para usar futuramente.

Segue o exemplo do dataframe:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu gostaria de substituir o número de linhas por esse 10 para deixar mais automatico.

```
i = 0
lista = []

while i < 10:
  lin = x.loc[i]['index']
  p = yf.Ticker(lin)
  lista.append(p.info)
  lista.append("-----------------------")
  i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi bem você quer substituir aquel `10` fixo pelo número de linhas que foram geradas randomicamente no seu `dataframe`, é isso?

Neste caso você pode utilizar o método `shape` que mostra a quantidade de **linhas** e **colunas** de um `dataframe`. Você pode, inclusive, fazer o seguinte para ter cada um desses valores armazenado em uma variável:

```
linhas, colunas = dataframe.shape
```

depois é só usar essa info para o que você deseja, no seu caso:

```
i = 0
lista = []

while i < linhas:
  lin = x.loc[i]['index']
  p = yf.Ticker(lin)
  lista.append(p.info)
  lista.append("-----------------------")
  i = i + 1
```